# python array of unicodes to float conversion

Tags: python, unicode

I have an array which looks as:

```
MyArray
array(['1445.98', '1422.64', '1392.93', ..., '2012.21', '1861.19',
       '1681.02'], dtype=object)

type(MyArray[0])
```

I tried:

```
MyArray.astype(np.float)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: -
```

How do I convert MyArray to array of floats instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe convert each memeber individually. Try something like,

```
map(lambda x: float(x),mydata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously some of your lines don't have valid float data

```
map(lambda x: float(x),MyArray)
```

or

if you have a list

```
[float(x) for x in MyList]
```